# Smarty 3 math calculation

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

I can't seem to get the syntax correct for this: divide maths calculation.

```
{assign var="span" value="`12/$rows|@count`"}
```

Docs - http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.math.tpl

Comment: I must have tried every syntax possible, I think its impossible

Comment: How do you find site performance having Smarty do this much preprocessing. I've always been a little confused as to why so much functionality was required in Smarty?

Comment: Because its related to the view/template I am calculating the amount of columns for twitter bootstrap. Plus it interlinks with javascript much easier.

Comment: If it got more complicated I would move it into the controller, but for simple presentational logic: truncate/strip tags/escape I find smarty very useful. Small performance hit on first load but this gets cached smarty templates and HTML output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
{assign var="count" value=$rows|@count}
{math assign="span" equation='x/y' x=12 y=$count}
```

Ref: http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=66730

Comment: I am not sure about the first expression but the second one will work for sure